# Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined

Tags: javascript, store

I am writing a demo using [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/).
Briefly, there are two files `index.html` and `base.js` and the folder `node_mudules`.

I install the store.js by:

```
npm i store
```

In the index.html, it is referenced in the header:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/base.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/store/store.js"></script>
```

But when I tried to use it in the base.js like:

```
store.set('user', { name:'Marcus' })
```

This error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined
```

I am sure the path is correct, because it is referenced by the same way as jquery, and the jquery works well.

I also download the whole repo and copy the  `store.legacy.min.js` to my project, referenced in the header:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/base.js"></script>
<script src="./store.legacy.min.js"></script>
```

The same error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined
```

What is wrong? Any help gratefully received...

Comment: You need to include the script before you use it.

Comment: you strore js file is being referenced after your js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
<script src="node_modules/store/store.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/base.js"></script>
```